# Save file from ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, iframe, download

I want to save the image generated on the server. For this I use iframe, but the File Save dialog does not appear after the click. What am I doing wrong?

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#onv-save-button').click( function() {
                    $.ajax ({               
                        url: "/ajax.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(data) {
                            $('#downloadFrame').attr('src' , data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="" id="downloadFrame" ></iframe>
        <button id="onv-save-button">Go!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?  

    // Some actions to generate image
    echo "1.png" ;
?>
```

Comment: >> echo "1.png" -- do you see this text in your downloadFrame element?

Comment: You do know you're just printing "1.png" to the browser output?

Comment: I see my image in downloadFrame after click.

Comment: Where is your code for the file save dialog? The only code you have know is that it will echo `1.png` into the iframe after a click on `#onv-save-button`.

Comment: Could you give an example of this code?

Answer (score 0):

I did. Here is the answer to the question.

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#onv-save-button').click( function() {
                    $.ajax ({               
                        url: "/ajax.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                            $('#downloadFrame').attr('src' , "download.php?file=" + data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="" id="downloadFrame" ></iframe>
        <button id="onv-save-button">Go!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?  
    echo $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/1.png";
?>
```

download.php

```
<?php

    $content = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['file']);
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Cache-Control: ");
    header("Pragma: ");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($_REQUEST['file'])."\"");

    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start();
    echo $content;
    ob_end_flush();
    exit();

?>
```